# I want to call a method present in a stateful class from another stateful class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

There are two stateful widgets, I want to call a method present in one class from another onTap. Below is the brief code:

```
class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final String total;
  FirstClass(this.total);
  @override
  _FirstClassState createState() => _FirstClassState();
}
class _FirstClassStateState extends State<FirstClassState> {

Model getModel(abc){ //Model class is in another dart file
Model nModel = new Model();
nModel.n1 = abc;

}
next(){
setstate(){some code}
}
SecondClass (
model: getModel(s),
num:1,
)
}
class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final Model model;
  final int num;
 SecondClass({@required this.model, @required this.num});
  @override
  _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
}
class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
onTap(){ //I have to call the method next() from here }
}
========================================================================
```

Yes,the SecondClass is present inside widget tree of FirstClass

Comment: Is the SecondClass Widget inside the FirstClass Widget tree?.

Comment: Yes, SecondClass Widget inside the FirstClass Widget tree, edited the question for better understanding..thanks

Comment: Can I put next() method inside SecondClass and in onTap pass the values from next() to FirstClass and rebuild widget tree of FirstClass? Will it work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. If your `SecondClass` is within the `FirstClass` widget tree. You can create a `Function onTap()` constructor on the SecondClass and used that onTap on the FirstClass

```
class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstClassState createState() => _FirstClassState();
}

class _FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
  void next() {
    setState(() {
      // SOME CODE
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SecondClass(
            onTap: () => next(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onTap;

  const SecondClass({Key key, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
}

class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => widget.onTap(),
        child: Text("BUTTON"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I tried the same but passed just method: next() instead of method: ()=> next(), so didn't work..thanks for posting solution :)